# Is there a glitch that lets you fly in Breath of the Wild?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I've seen these crazy contraptions that are made by gamers that let them fly, but I have no idea how to make them, or if its just some camera trick. So are they real? And if they are, how do you do them?

Answer (score 5):

They are real and rely on a glitch in the physics engine. They use the magnetism power, but not to lift the object beneath them, but instead the object beneath THAT object. So you take a minecart or something else made of metal, then put something else on top of it. You can then stand on top of the top object and lift the minecart beneath it, and if you do it properly, the entire contraption with you on it will be lifted.

There are also at least 2 other ways to fly. The first way is by using Stasis on an object, hit it a couple of times, then jump on it before stasis runs out. The second way is by riding the blast wave of a bomb. I'm not entirely sure how that works, but it's a more dangerous trick that can kill you if you're not careful.

Comment: wow that was amazeing would you mind if I put it on a youtube channel ill give you credit

Comment: @linkofhyrule Sure. make sure to link to this post as required by the Stack Exchange license. For an in-depth tutorial on the flying mechanics, check out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r4RPNPsEyn8